Indexed Stack rebuilt issue flutter (windows)
We are developing a flutter desktop application and we are trying to implement tab navigation logic but the issue we are facing is, when we try to remove a page/widget from middle of indexed stack all
Widget children of indexed stack after Widget popped index are getting rebuild and we are loosing the state of widgets
provider -->>

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jms/src/features/dashboard/screens/dashboard.dart';


class TabManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  late TabController tabC;
  late PageController pageC;
  TickerProvider? tabVsync;
  final List<Widget> tabs = [
    const AppDashboard(),
    // const SalesInvoice(),
    // const SalesInvoice(),
    // const BalanceSheetScreen()
    // const MetalGroupMaster()
  ];

  void init(TickerProvider vsync) {
    tabVsync = vsync;
    tabC = TabController(
        length: tabs.length, vsync: vsync, initialIndex: tabs.length - 1);

    pageC = PageController(
      initialPage: tabs.length - 1,
    );
  }

  void addNewTab(Widget tab) {
    tabs.add(tab);

    tabC = TabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      vsync: tabVsync!,
      initialIndex: tabs.length - 1,
    );

    notifyListeners();
  }
}


--> tabsArea
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabManager = context.watch<TabManager>();
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: context.theme.appColors.tabBackgroundColor,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: context.theme.appColors.primaryAccent,
                    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(5), topLeft: Radius.circular(5))
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.005),
                width: size.width * 0.035,
                height: size.height * 0.04,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          tabManager.tabC.animateTo(0);
                          setState(() {

                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "Home",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                            fontFamily: "Lato"
                          ),
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: size.width * 0.935,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ...tabManager.tabs.mapIndexed(
                            (i, e) {

                          return i == 0 ? const SizedBox.shrink() : Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: context.theme.appColors.primary,

                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    // color: tabManager.tabC.index != i ? AppColors.primaryColor : AppColors.primaryColor,
                                    color: context.theme.appColors.primary,
                                      border: Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                              width: 2,
                                              color: tabManager.tabC.index == i ? context.theme.appColors.primaryAccent : context.theme.appColors.primary
                                          )
                                      )
                                    // borderRadius: tabManager.tabC.index == i ? const BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(5), topLeft: Radius.circular(5)) : null,
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.005),
                                  width: tabManager.tabs.length > 10 ? size.width * 0.07 :  size.width * 0.1,
                                  height: size.height * 0.04,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            tabManager.tabC.animateTo(i);
                                            setState(() {

                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            getFormattedWidgetName(e.toString()),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                                fontFamily: "Lato",
                                              color: context.theme.appColors.primaryTextColor
                                              // color: tabManager.tabC.index == i ? AppColors.whiteColor : AppColors.blackColor,
                                            ),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            bool isCurrentTab = tabManager.tabC.index == i;
                                            bool isBeforeCurrentTab = i < tabManager.tabC.index;

                                            tabManager.tabs.removeAt(i);

                                            int newIndex = isCurrentTab
                                                ? (tabManager.tabC.index > 0 ? tabManager.tabC.index - 1 : 0)
                                                : (isBeforeCurrentTab ? tabManager.tabC.index - 1 : tabManager.tabC.index);

                                            tabManager.tabC = TabController(
                                              length: tabManager.tabs.length,
                                              vsync: this,
                                              initialIndex: newIndex,
                                            );

                                            // Animate to the new current tab if necessary
                                            tabManager.tabC.animateTo(newIndex);
                                            // tabManager.tabC = TabController(
                                            //   length: tabManager.tabs.length,
                                            //   vsync: this,
                                            //   initialIndex: tabManager.tabC.index > 0
                                            //       ? tabManager.tabC.index - 1
                                            //       : 0,
                                            // );
                                            //
                                            // tabManager.tabC.animateTo(
                                            //   tabManager.tabs.length - 1 == tabManager.tabC.index ? tabManager.tabC.index : tabManager.tabC.index > 0
                                            //       ? tabManager.tabC.index + 1
                                            //       : 0,
                                            // );
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.close,
                                          // color: tabManager.tabC.index == i ? AppColors.whiteColor : AppColors.blackColor,
                                          color: context.theme.appColors.primaryIconColor,
                                          size: 20,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                if(i == tabManager.tabs.length -1 )
                                  const SizedBox.shrink()
                                else
                                  SizedBox( height: size.height * 0.02, child: const VerticalDivider(color: AppColors.blackColor, width: 2,))

                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: tabManager.tabC.index,
            children: tabManager.tabs,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

We tried using tabBarView, fluentUi TabView,pageview, AutomatickeepAliveMixin, even tried with Visibility and offstage , but the problem still persists

check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc
